# Access - Generate report using form with VB

Tags: ms-access

I have this table (**TABLE1**).

```
Name | IDCard | Class
Aba     123      A 
Ebe     456      B
Ibi     789      C
```

I have this query (**QUERY1**)

```
SELECT Name, IDCard FROM TABLE1;
```

Then, in the Report Assistant I choose **QUERY1**, I open the report generated, and it shows all the names and IDCards from **TABLE1**.

So now I create a form with a ComboBox called **NameStudents** and a button to preview the result.

Finally I open VB to code a filter for the report with the selected name like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "[Name] =" & Me!NameStudents
```

I simply want a form that selects names from a table and puts them in a Combobox, then the user selects one student, clicks preview, and a report will appear with name and IDCard.

I don't know why this doesn't work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the button have an OnClick property of `[Event Procedure]`?

Answer (score 1):

The question I would have is what happens when you hard code the name?

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "[Name] = John"
```

I have this feeling that your names actually have spaces in it, like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "[Name] = John Smith"
```

In which case, you might have to do this

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "[Name] = ""John Smith"""
```

or

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "[Name] = """ & Me!NameStudents & """"
```